# How to fix: I am getting a "No coercion operator" error only after a .Join with .Include

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using EF core 2.2, I am working on a search page, and I need to get only the newest(timestamp) form a custID. So the data can look like this.

AltId, CustID, ReceiveDate, name,...
1,   2,   Null,       bob...
1,   2,   2/9/2018,   bob...
1,   2,   2/5/2018,   bob...
1,   2,   1/10/2017,  bob...
2,   5,   1/6/2018,   Matt...
3,   7,   1/3/2018,   Kelly...
4,   9,   1/5/2018,   Sam...

The results I need are.. you can see I needed to filter out null and get the max date.
AltId, CustID, ReceiveDate, name,...
1,   2,   2/9/2018,   bob...
2,   5,   1/6/2018,   Matt...
3,   7,   1/3/2018,   Kelly...
4,   9,   1/5/2018,   Sam...

I am less worried about the details of the error. I don't want talk about the int and string. BUT rather why the .join is braking or changing the type of something. 
Also, any advice on how to debug this low-level EF error would help.

if I remove the .join, I get all the record and my array of custTransations is populated. (as I would suspect)
if I remove the .include I get the correct filtered data but custTransations null (as I would suspect)

````
 var query = Set.GroupBy(e => e.CustId)
                    .Select(e => new { CustId= e.Key, ReceiveDate = e.Max(m => m.ReceiveDate ) })
                    .AsQueryable();

                    data = await Set.Where(
                          e => e.IssueDate >= criteria.StartDate
                          && e.IssueDate <= criteria.EndDate)
                       .Where(e => e.CustTransactions.Any(
                           cat =>cat.Cust.Member.AltId == criteria.AltId
                           && cat.Cust.IsActive == true
                           && cat.IsActive == true)
                       .Join(query,
                            outer => new { outer.CustId, outer.ReceiveDate },
                            inner => new { inner.CustId, inner.ReceiveDate },
                            (outer, inner) => outer
                       )
                       .Include(e => e.CustTransactions)
                       .AsNoTracking()
                       .ToListAsync();  
    ```

No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Int32' and 'System.String'.
````

Comment: What is `critera`?

Comment: critera is the post object form the UI. so it hold the AltId and start/end date the UI is searching for. using this allowed me to use ModelState.IsValid

Comment: You might need to post a complete repro.  Is that query even complete?  `&& e.IssueDate <= critera.Where(...)` doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: update post, there are more filters that I can't share, but this query does work

Comment: ReceiveDate is a null-able date-time field in the database. yes type. post updated. that was a big miss on my part. that is the line that is breaking the generation of the SQL when I have the join.

Comment: Also including the full error message would help - "between types …", the most important information is after "...". Also the exception stack trace (might be EF Core bug - there are many).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a query generation bug/limitation in EF Core.  There are still many query shapes that EF Core can't translate to SQL, but most of them should fail with an intelligible error message.  This one just fails.  Below is a repro and a workaround.  Someone should see if this repros on EF Core 3, and [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues).

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SomeUI
{

    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Transactions> Transactions { get; } = new HashSet<Transactions>();

    }

    public class Transactions
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public DateTime TransDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class Db : DbContext
    {
        private string connectionString;

        public Db() : this("Server=.;Database=EfCoreTest;Integrated Security=true")
        { }
        public Db(string connectionString)
        {
            this.connectionString = connectionString;
        }
        public DbSet<Product> Products{ get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, b => b.UseRelationalNulls())
                 .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }



public class Program
    {



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();

                var p = new Product() { CategoryName = "A" };
                var tran = new Transactions() { Product = p, Quantity = 2, TransDate = DateTime.Now };

                db.Products.Add(p);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            using (var db = new Db())
            {

                var q = db.Products.GroupBy(p => p.CategoryName).Select(g => new { CategoryName = g.Key, UpdatedAt = g.Max(p => p.UpdatedAt) });


                var q2 =
                    from p in db.Products.Include(p => p.Transactions)
                    join r in q
                    on new { p.CategoryName, p.UpdatedAt } equals new { r.CategoryName, r.UpdatedAt }
                    select p;

                var q3 =
                    from p in db.Products.Include(p => p.Transactions)
                    where db.Products.Where(np => np.CategoryName == p.CategoryName).OrderByDescending(np => np.UpdatedAt).Take(1).Select(np => np.UpdatedAt).Contains(p.UpdatedAt)
                    select p;

                var q4 =
                 db.Products
                   .Include(p => p.Transactions)
                   .Where(p => db.Products
                                 .Where(np => np.CategoryName == p.CategoryName)
                                 .OrderByDescending(np => np.UpdatedAt)
                                 .Take(1)
                                 .Select(np => np.UpdatedAt)
                                 .Contains(p.UpdatedAt));

                //var results = q2.ToList(); //fails
                /*
                  System.InvalidOperationException
                  HResult=0x80131509
                  Message=No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.String' and 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]'.
                  Source=System.Linq.Expressions
                  StackTrace:
                   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetUserDefinedCoercionOrThrow(ExpressionType coercionType, Expression expression, Type convertToType)
                */
                var results = q3.ToList();  //works


                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Working so far, I am just converting my Lamda over to Linq to SQL and adding my over Where's.   Can you show me a Lamda example?